# Swagger/open api 3.0 links not rendered properly

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm creating an open api definition, and trying to define HATEOAS links from one route to another. The following yaml code is parsed correctly, but when running swagger-ui, the link is displayed strangely, with the value of `operationId` printed. Is this really intended? I was expecting something else, such as a hyperlink to the route depicted by the link. Am I doing something wrong?

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  description: "Foo API"
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "Foo"
paths:
  /foo: 
    get: 
      summary: Foo 
      operationId: getFoo
      responses: 
        200: 
          description: OK
  /bar: 
    get: 
      summary: Bar
      operationId: getBar
      responses: 
        200: 
          description: OK
          links:
            foo:
              operationId: getFoo
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: By "HATEOAS links", do you mean you want the links included in the response body, as in `{ ..., "links": { ... }}`?

Comment: No, in that case I would not document them as links, but as part of the response body. I mean that it would be nice if the UI was rendered so that there was a clickable link to the operation instead of an obscure `Operation getFoo Parameters {}`, which honestly just looks like the raw data was displayed as-is.

Comment: BTW, maybe I'm misunderstanding some concept of links here, but the way I use them, links are just `href` URL:s with a `rel`. The `href`s might be valid with several different HTTP methods, so one link could map to several operations. So shouldn't each link have an _array_ of operations, which the UI could render so that it's clear that invoking `GET` on the `foo` link will call the `getFoo` operation (actually, it should just link to that part of the API docs) while `PUT` on `foo` invokes another operation.

Comment: Indeed @helen, thanks for detecting.